# reducing html table's loading time with large numbers of data being queried | PHP, HTML, SQLSERVER 2012

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I'm experiencing a problem when loading the data from my database, the data is somewhat large enough to cause a delay.

I tried to add this in my code, but still not enough.

```
.fixed-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

I stumbled upon this guide. https://patdavid.net/2019/02/displaying-a-big-html-table/. So i tried to implement it, unfortunately my loading time is still the same.

With this line, how will I approach this

> I set the table to display: none; initially and once the document was ready I set it back to display: table; (relying on JavaScript to do this).

This is my table script

```
/* FOR CORPORATE DATA TABLE START */
function format ( dataSource ) {
    var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;" class="fixed-table table table-bordered">';
    for (var key in dataSource){
        html += '<tr>'+
                   '<td>' + key             +'</td>'+
                   '<td>' + dataSource[key] +'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
    } return html += '</table>';  }
var earnings_amendment_table = $('#earnings_amendment').DataTable({});

      // Add event listener for opening and closing details
      $('#earnings_amendment').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var row = earnings_amendment_table.row(tr);

          if (row.child.isShown()) {
              // This row is already open - close it
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              // Open this row
              row.child(format({
                  'Particulars : ' : tr.data('key-1'),
                  'Account Type : ' : tr.data('key-2'),
                  'Date Due : ' :  tr.data('key-3')
              })).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
          } });
/* FOR CORPORATE DATA TABLE END */
```

This is the table

```
    <div class="box-body">
              <table id="earnings_amendment" class="fixed-table table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Reference ID.</th>
                  <th>Reference No.</th>
                  <th>Employee Name</th>
                  <th>Account Title</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                  <th>Activity</th>
                  <th>Posted By</th>
                  <th>Validated By</th>
                  <th>Noted By</th>
                  <th>Tools</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
$sql = "
select earningsamendment.particulars,earningsamendment.accounttype,earningsamendment.datedue,
employeemasterfile.lastname,employeemasterfile.firstname,employeemasterfile.middlename,
referenceno, accounttitle, max(credit) as credit, max(debit) as debit, max(referenceid) as referenceid, earningsamendment.employeeidno,
earningsamendment.postedby, approvedby, notedby
from earningsamendment
left join employeemasterfile on earningsamendment.employeeidno= employeemasterfile.employeeidno
WHERE earningsamendment.accounttitle='$accounttitle' AND 
YEAR(earningsamendment.dateposted)='$year'
group by referenceno, earningsamendment.employeeidno, accounttitle, earningsamendment.postedby, approvedby,
notedby,employeemasterfile.lastname,employeemasterfile.firstname,employeemasterfile.middlename,
earningsamendment.particulars,earningsamendment.accounttype,earningsamendment.datedue
";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                      <tr data-key-1='".$row['particulars']."' data-key-2='".$row['accounttype']."' data-key-3='".$row['datedue']."'>
                        <td class='details-control'></td>
                          <td>".$row['referenceid']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['referenceno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['lastname']." ".$row['middlename']." ".$row['firstname']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttitle']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['credit']."</td>
                          <td>".(($row['debit']==$row['credit']) ? 'PAID' : 'FOR TAKE UP' )."</td>
                          <td>".$row['postedby']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['approvedby']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['notedby']."</td>
                          <td>
                            <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat' data-id='".$row['referenceid']."'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Preview</button>

                            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat' data-id='".$row['referenceid']."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>

                        " ?>
                            <?php if (empty($row['approvedby'])) { echo " <button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm approve btn-flat' data-id='".$row['referenceid']."'><i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i> Approve</button> "; } ?>

                            <?php if (empty($row['notedby'])) { echo " <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm note btn-flat' data-id='".$row['referenceid']."'><i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-right'></i> Note</button> "; } ?>

                            <?php "</td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
```

The total data being loaded is around **300,000-500,000**. It's taking so long for it to load. up to 60-70 seconds. Is there a way for us to reduce this time? Is the structure of my table/query wrong, is there any possible solution to reduce this delay?

I tried to use clusterize.js, but I can't seem to be able to implement it.

> ADDENDUM: Is there a way for this to be implemented into SQL SERVER 2012?https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php

I'm planning to do this via Server-Side, but I'm worried that I may change all the tables that I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use pagination and filtering to make the table usable.

Comment: May I ask on how to approach that? I'm currently using Client-Side dataTable .

Comment: Pagination is to split the content of your table into multiple tables. Say for instance you have 500 records to be displayed. By using pagination of page size 100, you can show your data in 5 pages. This will considerable reduce your loading time.And Filtering may be used to show specific results your need based on a filter criteria. https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html is a tutorial on how you can use pagination,

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

use data tables jQuery plug-in, it can handle displaying large data in the table representation with less time

```
Reference :: https://datatables.net/
```

I personally used it.
When I am trying to display large chunk of data from mysql using normal table references, it used to take lot of time to load
Using datatables jQuery plug-in solved the issue

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 2012, not all of the commands are available in dataTable.

Comment: I also tried this - https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables but it's only for MySQL and not for SQL SERVER